# Undeclared income - more than 2 years

Tags: income-tax, india

I have undeclared income that is more than 2 years (Exactly 2 years and 2 months), in a US bank account.

I would like to bring that money to India. Can I bring that money back to India, declare it now and pay tax on the same ?. Kindly advise.

Thanks

Comment: This has too many variables and the information you supply is minimal. Dheer is right, you need professional help. Acting on the advice of strangers on the internet will be harmful to you.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the nature of the income. Please consult a professional CPA for specific advise.